# no match for call to `(rectangle) (double, double)'

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
class rectangle
{
    double length,width;

public:
    rectangle()
    {
        length=0;
        width=0;
    }

    rectangle(double len,double wid)
    {
        length=len;
        width=wid;
    }

    double display()
    {
        return(length*width);
    }

    rectangle operator+(rectangle& rect)
    {
        rectangle recta;
        recta.length=this->length+rect.length;
        recta.width=this->width+rect.width;
        return rectangle(length,width);
    }
};

int main()
{
    rectangle rect1,rect2,rect3;
    rect1(7.0,8.9);
    rect2(11.4,12.8);
    rect3=rect1+rect2;
    cout<<rect1.display()<<endl;
    cout<<rect2.display()<<endl;
    cout<<rect3.display()<<endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not able to find why it is giving an error.

Comment: You should provide the line on which the error occurs.

Comment: `rectangle rect1;rect1(7.0,8.9);` Constructors don't work this way. Try `rectangle rect1(7.0,8.9);`

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fbd1e4383cfbd66;

Comment: Vivek, aren't you going to say something about any answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should call the constructor when you declare the object like this:

```
rectangle rect1(7.0, 8.9);
```

Otherwise, you are not actually calling the constructor, but the operator `()`, which you haven't defined somewhere in your class, leading to an error.

---

Also, the **overload of the `+` operator** is not correct, since you return this: `return rectangle(length,width);`, where you should actually return `recta`, since this is the object on which you have applied the operator.

Putting them all together, your program should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class rectangle
{
    double length,width;

public:
    rectangle()
    {
        length=0;
        width=0;
    }

    rectangle(double len,double wid)
    {
        length=len;
        width=wid;
    }

    double display()
    {
        return(length*width);
    }

    rectangle operator+(const rectangle& rect) const
    {
        rectangle recta;
        recta.length=this->length+rect.length;
        recta.width=this->width+rect.width;
        return recta;
    }
};

int main()
{
    rectangle rect1(7.0, 8.9), rect2(11.4,12.8), rect3;
    rect3=rect1+rect2;
    cout<<rect1.display()<<endl;
    cout<<rect2.display()<<endl;
    cout<<rect3.display()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `rectangle operator+(const rectangle& rect) const`

Comment: @Bathsheba I would agree, if you have any other good comment like this, please share it with us! :)

Answer (score 0):

`rect1(7.0, 8.9);` is attempting to find an overload for `operator()(double, double)`, which you haven't implemented.

Did you mean `rectangle rect1(7.0, 8.9);` etc? That's how you call a *constructor*.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
rect1(7.0,8.9);
```

is calling `operator()` on your rectangle object, however you have not defined this operator which is why you get that error.  I think what you wanted to do was call the constructor, which you have to do when you instantiate the object, like this:

```
rectangle rect1(7.0, 8.9);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's at least a problem there:

```
rectangle rect1,rect2,rect3;
rect1(7.0,8.9);
rect2(11.4,12.8);
```

You must provide construction parameters at the location that the object is defined. Otherwise, the compiler thinks you're calling a function.

```
rectangle rect1(7.0,8.9);
rectangle rect2(11.4,12.8);
rectangle rect3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined a constructor, but are trying to use a call overload.

Constructors, the methods that have the same name as the struct/class, are only used when you initially build the thing, typically at the initial declaration point. You wrote:

```
         rectangle rect1,rect2,rect3; 
         rect1(7.0,8.9); 
         rect2(11.4,12.8);
```

The first line calls the default constructor and then the rectangle is built. The next lines try to call them as a function - since they are already made, it no longer tries to construct. (Specifically, it is trying to call `operator()(double,double)` now).

To fix this, you should initialize/construct them right at the declaration point:

```
rectangle rect1(7.0, 8.9);
rectangle rect2(11.4, 12.8);
rectangle rect3 = rect1 + rect2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
rect1(7.0,8.9);
```

does not call `rectangle` constructor. It is calling `rect1` like a function; technically, it is calling `rectangle::operator()`. Since `rectangle` doesn't have such an operator, you get compilation error.

If you wanted to call the constructor, the correct syntax is

```
rectangle rect1(7.0, 8.9);
```